# how to change status by a link or a button in django

Tags: django

So I want to make a link or a button that should be able to change status from 1 to 0 in the database actually I have the link like this `<a href="{% url 'articles:delete' slug=article.slug %}" class="btn btn-danger mr-1 float-left">Delete</a>`  and in url.py `path('delete-article/<slug:slug>/', views.delete_article, name='delete'),` now I want to make a function in views.py that change the status to 0 whenever the link is clicked

models.py

```py
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Articles (models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    body = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    thumb = models.ImageField(blank=True, default='{% static "Images/default.jpg" %}',)
    Category = models.ForeignKey(Category, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def snippet(self):
        return self.body[:120]
```

Comment: Pleas share the model for the article. Do *not* use a GET request, that is not HTTP compliant.

Comment: this the model.py file. No, I didn't use the GET method I was trying with POST but didn't understand how to do it.

Comment: `<a href="...">` is a link, and will result in a GET request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with [**`.update(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update):

```
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods

@require_http_methods(['POST'])
def delete_article(request, slug):
    Articles.objects.filter(slug=slug).update(status=0)
    # …
```

But you should *not* work with a link. This is a GET request, and GET requests should, by the HTTP standard be used to [*retrieve* data, not *change* data [w3.org]](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.1.1):

> In particular, the convention has been established that the GET and HEAD methods **SHOULD NOT have the significance of taking an action other than retrieval**. These methods ought to be considered "safe".

You thus make a POST request, for example with a mini-form:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'articles:delete' slug=article.slug %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger mr-1 float-left">Delete</button>
</form>
```